# Compiling Optimized Analytics Package for Spark Platform with sbt

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to compile the [Optimized Analytics Package for Spark Platform](https://github.com/Intel-bigdata/OAP) with sbt.

I copied the `libraryDependencies` from the `pom.xml` file into the  `build.sbt` file, but I am still getting the following 12 errors.

1. `SparkSqlParser.scala:1411:41: not found: type OapCreateIndexContext`
2. `SparkSqlParser.scala:1428:39: not found: type OapDropIndexContext`
3. `SparkSqlParser.scala:1436:36: not found: type IndexColsContext`
4. `SparkSqlParser.scala:1440:35: not found: type IndexColContext`
5. `SparkSqlParser.scala:1444:36: not found: type IndexTypeContext`
6. `SparkSqlParser.scala:1456:44: not found: type OapRefreshIndicesContext`
7. `SparkSqlParser.scala:1463:39: not found: type OapShowIndexContext`
8. `SparkSqlParser.scala:1468:40: not found: type OapCheckIndexContext`
9. `BloomFilterStatistics.scala:115:65: overloaded method value subsets with alternatives:`
10. `SQLConf.scala:653:57: overloaded method value subsets with alternatives:`
11. `OapIndexInfoStatusSerDe.scala:43:61: No org.json4s.Formats found. Try to bring an instance of org.json4s.Formats in scope or use the org.json4s.DefaultFormats.`
12. ``` OapIndexInfoStatusSerDe.scala:44:7: missing arguments for method indexStatusRawDataFromJson in object OapIndexInfoStatusSerDe; follow this method with ``_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function ```

Do I need to `addSbtPlugin()` to my `build.sbt` file that are equivalent to the maven plugins listed in the `pom.xml` file?

The maven plugins in the `pom.xml` file are:

1. `maven-shade-plugin`
2. `scalastyle-maven-plugin`
3. `scala-maven-plugin`
4. `scalatest-maven-plugin`
5. `maven-compiler-plugin`
6. `antlr4-maven-plugin`
7. `maven-jar-plugin`

Comment: Why not building it with Maven?

Comment: Not installed, and waiting for corporate IT to install it.  Though that may never happen.

Comment: You do not need any privileges to install maven. Just download, unpack and add to your local PATH variable